# Get Form Id of all the forms linked to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I have a Google Spreadsheet in which multiple forms are linked each forming a tab in the sheet. If I use below code -

```
function test() {
     var resp = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getFormUrl();  
     Logger.log(resp);
}
```

I get the form Url of only the form linked to 1st tab. Is there a way to get the url of all the forms ?

Comment: There is no way to get all the linked Forms through the Spreadsheet Service if there is more than one linked Form.

Answer (score 0):

There are several threads on this topic, but when looking for all the linked forms, the common suggestion is to search through the spreadsheet's directory looking for forms and request the spreadsheet ID of the form's destination. I'm concerned, however, that a form may be moved, or created in a different directory and thus won't be found.
Here's what I determined;
Pressing F12 opens the browser debugger, and in there you will find the IDs of all the linked forms, next to the gid of their respective sheets.
Unfortunately, I don't have the time or expertise to go digging around in the HTML code (I can in VBA, but not in GAS just yet).
But it seems you just get the gid of the sheet accepting form data (which you know), go into the HTML code, find that gid and look nearby to find the ID of the linked form.
Then repeat.